# PHP pass variable to include & Paypal IPN

Tags: php, paypal

After a customer buy on the site, Paypal loads the "notify_url" page in which i run code to add to my database the information.

So in my "notify_url" file "file1.php", there is something like this ($_POST['a'] = 77):

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
$_POST['b'] = 88;
$_SESSION['test'] = 'test'; 
$action = 'buy';

include('file2.php');
```

... and in file2.php:

```
echo $a; // result: ""
echo $action; // result: ""
echo $_SESSION['test']; // result: ""
echo $_POST['b']; // result: ""
echo $_POST['a']; result: "77"
```

Why do my variable don't follow in the include, but the POST does?

Comment: If you `include` a file the code inherits the scope of the calling file. The variables should be accessible unless you've changed the scope. $_POST is a superglobal - i.e it's accessible anywhere. I suspect the second snippet is inside a function, but you haven't shown us the function declaration.

Comment: When i do the same call from another file, but directly on my site (not paypal), everything works (all variable keep their value). Ex: if  i send an email from an email form and call "file2.php" from that file, everything is fine. It's only really happens when it's coming from Paypal IPN bot. Could it be some security feature in PHP that blocks "includes" when the file is called from an external bot?

Comment: _Could it be some security feature_ - no.